# Can't use Subversion command line client: svn , Errors found while detecting svn working copies. Fix it

Tags: intellij-idea, svn, tortoisesvn

I am getting the below errors in my Intellij Idea project. How can I fix them?

[image]

Comment: To Fix it, did you try to click on the link that says "Fix it"? Maybe that will Fix it?

Comment: Yes I tried it providing path of svn.exe, but it pop again.

Comment: @HargunSuri What Subversion `.exe` file do you use? Please provide the full path and the output of the `svn.exe --version`.

Comment: Path : C:\Program Files\SlikSvn\bin\svn.exe and
Output result : svn, version 1.9.7-SlikSvn (SlikSvn/1.9.7)

Comment: @HargunSuri try to install and use the path for TortoiseSVN instead.

Answer (score 1):

Installed new version of SVN and it worked.